# Range Slider changing value to default on click outside the slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three range sliders and the issue is only with the first slider. If I set a value on the first slider and click outside it, it will change to the default value.

````
    function p() {
        a("#emi-widget-iframeinner").html('<div class="container-calculator"><form id="emi-formwrapper" class="no-pad"><h2 class="title-emi-calculator">Business Loan EMI Calculator</h2><div id="emi-form"><div class="form-group"> <label for="emi-loanamount" class="control-label">Loan Amount</label> <p class="emi-value">Rs.<span id="emi-principalAmount"></p></span> <div class="input-group"><p class="emi-tooltip tooltip-left">1 lac</p> <p class="emi-tooltip tooltip-right">2 cr</p><input type="range" class="form-control emi-userinput slider" id="emi-loanamount" onchange="principalAmount()" min="100000" max="20000000" value="100000" steps="100000" tabindex="1" placeholder="Loan Amount"/> </div></div></div></div>');```


HTML and JavaScript.

<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>EMI Calculator Widget</title><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/widget.css"/><script src="js/emicalc-lib.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="js/emicalc-main.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
        function principalAmount() {
          var x = document.getElementById("emi-loanamount").value;
          document.getElementById("emi-principalAmount").innerHTML = x;
        }

        function loanInterest() {
          var y = document.getElementById("emi-loaninterest").value;
          document.getElementById("emi-loanInterest").innerHTML = y;
        }

        function loanPeriod() {
          var y = document.getElementById("emi-loanterm").value;
          document.getElementById("emi-loanPeriod").innerHTML = y;
        }
        </script>

</head><body><div id="emi-widget-iframeinner"></div></body></html>
````

Comment: Can you minimize the code and remove nonrelated dependencies of the issue?

Comment: Thank you, bro. But I fixed the issue. The issue was blur calling it multiple times.